# How can I protect a binary file for being downloaded from a web folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

I am working on a CMS template generator. The users will download the generated template and they will use it on their web server. The template contains a binary file with all important data needed if a user wants to restore the template in the template generator for further changes.

If somebody can download this file, basically, can stole the template. How can I protect this file for being downloaded?

Var. 1:  .htaccess

How safe is to use .htaccess? I'm thinking that sometimes, when copying the files it my be lost (being a hidden file on UNIX like platforms) or it may not work on some servers (other than Apache).

Var. 2: .php extension

I was thinking to use .php extension, forcing the web server to parse the content (if somebody tries to access the file directly). Could this be a reliable solution?

Do you know another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect file using .htaccess or other way is you can upload binary files to bin folder on your web server which is not accessible to end users.

.htaccess code

```
<FilesMatch .bin>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 4):

The safest way is to keep the file somewhere outside the web server's content directory. That way, your code can still refer to it, but the web server itself ignores it completely.

Comment: I can't put it outside because it will be bundled with the template in an archive and for sure many users will upload it like this on the web server.

Comment: In that case use .htaccess, or if you can't trust yourself to copy the file over, perhaps set up the access in the VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0):

var 2: no it really isn't. If you put this into php file

```
hello world
```

it will output

> hello world

PHP is parsed only in  tags

Comment: If it's a binary file then the PHP interpreter might choke on it and err out. I wouldn't want to rely on that, though.

Comment: Being a binary file it displays some strange characters and question marks, I suppose that nobody can get the binary data from that.

Comment: Actually they can get the binary data from that very easily, it's no protection at all.